# Magento 2 deploy 1 pub static file

Tags: magento2, deploy, static-content-deploy

have a question, maybe somebody knows - **how to add to deploy version only 1 pub static file in production mode** without flush all deploy version.

For example, i have some customer-side uploader and needs to show these files, all is ok but when Magento setup on production mode these files not showing and needs regenerate all deploy version. maybe exists some ways to do this with only 1 file?

thanks...

Comment: Question is unclear to me.  You want to only re-deploy 1 of the static files, and not all of them that are usually compiled?  You are looking for a command to do only 1 static file in 1 language correct?

Comment: yep, and if this is possible of course do this without command line.
maybe some helpers or models provide this functionality

Comment: Hey @SlavaYurthev did you solve this? Looking for something similar